# Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

while i'm using the following sql query the output gave me operand should contain one column is there any way to solve it

```
String sql5 = "select distinct words.word from sentence.words where words.word not in ((select countries.country, horoofs.horoof from sentence.horoofs,sentence.countries))";
```

Comment: Your subquery, when using an `IN` operator should only return a single column otherwise it's nonsense. `WHERE words.word NOT IN ( single column returned, or a comma seperated list of 'words' )`

Answer (score 0):

You can only select one column in the below Statement.

```
 ((select countries.country, horoofs.horoof from sentence.horoofs,sentence.countries))
```